# Inserting and querying png and jpg files from db

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012 I need to insert and query icons from the database. What type of column should I use? General binary or image type specific?

Can someone refer me to an example (c#)?

Thanks.

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image type is deprecated, use should use varbinary(max).
[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms187993.aspx)
[referecne 2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510662.aspx)

for posting an exmple we would have to know with which "language" you are accessing the DB.